# AgGrid Enterprise not validating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

```
import * as agGrid from "ag-grid-enterprise";
agGrid.LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("license_key");
```

I have the following code in my index.js file, but i keep receiving the following error in :

```
main.js?c69b:114Uncaught TypeError: main_1.Grid.setEnterpriseComponents is not a function
```

im using 18.0.1 for both ag-grid and ag-grid-enterprise. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this, but this is what I had to do to resolve it:

```
import * as agGridEnterprise from 'ag-grid-enterprise';
agGridEnterprise.LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("your key");
```